# travis go error 'The command "eval go get -t -v ./..." failed'

Tags: go, travis-ci, hugo

I have a pretty straightforward setup.. 
- a Travis.yml file : https://github.com/openassistive/OpenATFrontEnd/blob/master/.travis.yml

which has this line:

```
before_script:
   - go get -u -v github.com/spf13/hugo
```

but it fails - with

> The command "eval go get -t -v ./..." failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.

(https://travis-ci.org/openassistive/OpenATFrontEnd/builds/166105574)
I can't figure it out. I see the language is set correctly - and looking at other SO posts the version number is correct. Is there a different version I should be using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read [this](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go#Dependency-Management), the `go get ....` is part of the default go build script on travis, if no makefile is found.

A simple solution may be to add a Makefile with an [empty recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Empty-Recipes.html)

```
$ cat Makefile
target: ;
$ make && echo "ok"
make: « target » uptodate.
ok
```

So travis will set the default install step to true, which should avoid the `got get`

Comment: Wonderful. This worked for me. Spared me some great amount of time. Thank you :)