# travis error: The command "go get -u -v github.com/spf13/hugo" failed and exited with 1 during

Tags: go, travis-ci, hugo

I receive the following error while trying to build my hugo blog with travis:

> The command "go get -u -v github.com/spf13/hugo" failed and exited with 1 during .

I have tried to create a makefile with an empty recipe as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937224/travis-go-error-the-command-eval-go-get-t-v-failed), but had no success. Here is the [build log](https://travis-ci.org/gtpedrosa/gtpedrosa.github.io/builds/310874054).

Any suggestions on how to avoid this error?

Comment: @Flimzy It does. The accepted answer of a similar question which i linked mentions the use of a makefile with an empty recipe, which i threw in the Repo main folder together with .travis.yml, but had no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go get` doesn't really work with Hugo -- or to be more precise: The behaviour is undefined.

Hugo vendors its dependencies, but does not commit those to the GitHub repo. So you would have to use `dep` and `mage`(a Go variant of Make) -- and the easiest way is to look at this Travis setup:

https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/.travis.yml

Note that if this is to get a working CI setup to build Hugo sites, I would recommend just to fetch one of the releases from here via `curl` or `wget`:

https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases

Comment: I'll take a look at the options, I was not aware of them. And yes it is to get a working CI setup to build my hugo blog. Thanks for taking a look into this! I'll get back with the results asap

Comment: fetching hugo with wget worked for me. Now [my build](https://travis-ci.org/gtpedrosa/gtpedrosa.github.io/jobs/313427676) is passing. Thank you! :)